# Asynchronous Countdowns in Python

Tags: python, terminal, python-asyncio, countdown

using: python 3.8 on windows 10

I am working on a script that runs in a while loop.
At the end of the loop I want it to wait for 5 seconds for the user to give input and then restart, or exit if they do not give input.

I've never actually used it before but I assumed asyncio would be useful because it allows for the definition of awaitables. However bringing things together is proving more difficult than I'd anticipated.

```py
import keyboard, asyncio, time as t



async def get():
    keyboard.record('enter', True)
    return True

async def countdown(time):
    while time > 0:
        print(f'This program will exit in {int(time)} seconds. Press enter to start over.', end='\r')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # t.sleep(1)
        time -= 1
    print(f'This program will exit in 0 seconds. Press enter to start over.', end='\r')
    return False


async def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        # other code
        
        
        clock = asyncio.create_task(countdown(5))
        check = asyncio.create_task(get())
        
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait({clock, check}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        running = next(iter(done)).result()
        print(running, end='\r')
    print('bye')
        

asyncio.run(main())
```

As it stands, the process doesn't end if I wait for five seconds. It also doesn't *visibly* count down (my best, and most ridiculous, guess is that it may be looping too fast in `main`? Try holding down the "enter" key - with and without printing `running`).
Also, when I switch to `time.sleep`, the display works fine, but it doesn't seem as though the `countdown` function ever returns.

Previously I'd tried using an `input` statement instead of `keyboard.record`; that blocks. I had also tried using `asyncio.wait_for`; but the timeout never came, though again, the "enter" key was registered (that said, it wouldn't have printed the countdown even if it had worked). I also tried `asyncio.as_completed` but I was unable to parse anything useful from the iterable. Happy to be wrong there though!

Also, bonus points if you can generalize the countdown to non-integer time spans <3

---

The `wait_for` approach:

```py
async def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        
        try:
            running = await asyncio.wait_for(get(), 5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            running = False
        print(running)
    print('bye')


asyncio.run(main())
```

---

`as_completed`

```py
async def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        ## other code
        clock = asyncio.create_task(countdown(5))
        check = asyncio.create_task(get())
        for f in asyncio.as_completed({check, clock}):
            # print(f.cr_frame)
            # print(f.cr_await, f.cr_running, f.cr_origin, f.cr_frame, f.cr_code)
            print(f.cr_await, f.cr_running, f.cr_origin)
            
    print('bye')
```

---

Also, bonus points if you can generalize the countdown to non-integer time :P

### cheers!

Comment: Your root problem is that the keyboard library you are using is not async, as indicated by the fact that the `get()` function doesn't await anything. An async function that doesn't await is async in name only and won't allow parallelization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the [docs for keyboard.record](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardrecorduntilescape-suppressfalse-trigger_on_releasefalse) it says:

> Note: this is a blocking function.

This is why your process didn't end after 5 seconds. It was blocking at `keyboard.record('enter', True)`. If you are going to stick with the keyboard module, what you need to do is create a hook on the 'enter' key. I put a quick demo together with your code:

```
import asyncio
import keyboard


class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enter_pressed = asyncio.Event()
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def get(self):
        await self.enter_pressed.wait()
        return True

    @staticmethod
    async def countdown(time):
        while time > 0:
            print(f'This program will exit in {int(time)} seconds. Press enter to start over.')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            # t.sleep(1)
            time -= 1
        print(f'This program will exit in 0 seconds. Press enter to start over.')
        return False

    def notify_enter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.enter_pressed.set)


    async def main(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            # other code

            keyboard.on_press_key('enter', self.notify_enter)
            self.enter_pressed.clear()
            clock = asyncio.create_task(self.countdown(5))
            check = asyncio.create_task(self.get())

            done, pending = await asyncio.wait({clock, check}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            keyboard.unhook('enter')
            for task in pending:
                task.cancel()

            running = next(iter(done)).result()
            print(running)

        print('bye')


async def main():
    program = Program()
    await program.main()

asyncio.run(main())
```

There is callback created `notify_enter`, that sets an `asyncio.Event` whenever it's fired. The `get()` task waits for this event to trigger before it exits. Since I didn't know what your other code is doing, we don't bind a hook to the enter key's key_down event until right before you await both tasks and we unbind it right after one of the tasks completes. I wrapped everything up in a class so the event is accessible in the callback, since there isn't a way to pass parameters in.

Comment: The `on_press_key` callback (`notify_enter`) is invoked in a separate thread, so you should use `call_soon_threadsafe` to invoke it, i.e. `self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.enter_pressed.set)`.

Comment: Thanks, W1ndstorm! You set the hook at the perfect place too. I managed to incorporate your fix by turning the ```notify_enter``` function into a wrapper on a separate function which handles the callback and sets the hook. I assigned ```enter_pressed``` immediately before ```on_press_key``` and passed it to get.

Comment: @user4815162342, what would be stored in ```self._loop``` in that scenario? And how do I know when I'm in a different thread? Thanks.

Comment: @kendfss You'd store the event loop used by asyncio by executing `self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` in `Program`'s `__init__`. The callback registered with `on_press_key` must be invoked by a different thread because your thread goes on to do other things, so `keyboard` "obviously" has its own background thread that monitors the keyboard and invokes the registered callbacks.

Comment: @kendfss To observe the issue solved by `call_soon_threadsafe`, try removing the countdowns or make them spaced wider apart. You'll notice that awaiting the event doesn't trigger as soon as you press something on the keyboard, but only at the next countdown. This is because `self.enter_passed.set()` is executed from another thread and doesn't properly wake up the event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342, thanks! I noticed that but I just assumed there was no way around it.

Comment: @user4815162342 good catch, I updated the example